# Multiple POST requests to same file from same IP address

Tags: apache-2.2, php, security

I periodically check my apache domlog to check for anomalies in GET and POST requests. Earlier today I noticed the same POST request to a login php happening two and sometimes three times a second for 2-3 hours from the same IP address. I am assuming it is someone trying to hack into an account.

What is the best way to guard against this? I could blacklist the IP but of course they could just use a proxy or switch IP addresses. Is there a better way to do this server side?

This server is running CentOS 6.4

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to automatically blacklist hosts after a certain number of failed logins.  This means that even if an attacker switches their ip address they will simply get blocked again after a small number of tries.

`fail2ban` unblocks addresses after a configureable amount of time, so this won't result in an address being block indefinitely.

If you own the PHP code you could obviously accomplish something similar in your web application (basically, rate limit failed logins coming from the same client ip address).

Comment: I suppose this is similar in function to cPHulk Brute Force Protection, which is something I already have.  If you have used cPHulk would you say fail2ban > cPHulk, or are they pretty much the same?

Comment: I'm not familiar with cPHulk but if it didn't stop the attack, maybe it's not configured right?

Comment: [cPHulk](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/CPHulk) is a Brute Force Protection tool for cPanel/WHM logins only. This will not help protect your website content from brute force attacks. I am assuming this is some kind of CMS that you are seeing multiple `POST` requests on. You may want to do some research for a plugin for that particular piece of software to help mitigate brute force attacks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with cPHulk or cPanel in general.  Reading the documentation at http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/CPHulk I don't see any mention of support for web servers...it appears to target POP and IMAP servers.  But I didn't read it in any detail.

Comment: fail2ban scans log files and is written in python, it's very ineffective way.

Comment: GioMac, I don't see any supporting documentation.  Can you elaborate on why you find it ineffective?  "Written in Python" isn't germane to the effectiveness of a tool, and I'm reasonably sure that on most systems `fail2ban` follows log files using efficient mechanisms, rather than polling. It supports a variety of applications, is easy to configure, and uses `iptables` as the actual blocking mechanism, which is a performance advantage over application-based blocks (such as any Apache module based solution), since connections are blocked by the kernel before they are handled by the application.

Comment: following log files is already ineffective. modsecurity can execute anything outside apache, even send message to external unit like hardware appliance and block it before it even reaches kernel :) Why should I generate tons of gigabytes of log files? How will you identify something to be blocked by the logs? logs won't show you everything. can you provide an apache+fail2ban example? :)

Comment: @GioMac Apache already generates logs. And fail2ban works great with them.

Comment: not always generates, not always complete, not always in single file. fail2ban just works, scanning every single line of file is not a great.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [modsecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org/) to define any rule you want, block intensive requests with time-based blocking, by counting requests, blacklist, run external app (i.e. block with firewall), forward to proxy, drop packet, reject connection, reset connection, redirect, display 404 error (ir maybe you like error 666), play with variables etc. It can do many things: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual

Example: http://halfelf.org/2013/wp-login-protection-modsec/

```
SecAction phase:1,nolog,pass,initcol:ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR},initcol:user=%{REMOTE_ADDR},id:5000134
<Locationmatch "/login.php">
    # deny status and log, 401 to client
    SecRule user:bf_block "@gt 0" "deny,status:401,log,id:5000135,msg:'ip address blocked for 5 minutes, more than 10 login attempts in 3 minutes.'"

    # Tracking:  On a successful login, a 302 redirect is performed, a 200 indicates login failed.
    SecRule RESPONSE_STATUS "^302" "phase:5,t:none,nolog,pass,setvar:ip.bf_counter=0,id:5000136"

    # count last 3 minutes
    SecRule RESPONSE_STATUS "^200" "phase:5,chain,t:none,nolog,pass,setvar:ip.bf_counter=+1,deprecatevar:ip.bf_counter=1/180,id:5000137"

    # if matched 10 times, block for 5 minutes
    SecRule ip:bf_counter "@gt 10" "t:none,setvar:user.bf_block=1,expirevar:user.bf_block=300,setvar:ip.bf_counter=0"
</locationmatch>
```